# How to use "clear away"

Tags: grammar

Are the following sentences correct English?

> - The crane just above the car has cleared away.
> - The car in front of the my house has just cleared away.

Answer (score -1):

The first sentence is incomplete, it doesn't say **what** the crane cleared away. It could be something like:

> The crane just above the car has cleared away the fallen tree.

The second sentence has no clear meaning at all. If it is intended to mean that the car was moved by someone, it could be one of:

> - The car in front of the my house has just been driven away.
> - The car in front of the my house was just driven away.

(if under the car's own power), or:

> - The car in front of the my house was just moved away.
> - The car in front of the my house was just cleared away.

Comment: I would wish that if anyone thinks this answer is incorrect or insufficient, that person would indicate the issue or issues, rather than silently downvoting. That would help learners, and might allow me to improve the answer.